# Why is the LT3080 input voltage limited to 36V?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

The [LT3080](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Linear%20Technology%20PDFs/LT3080_Rev.C_DS.pdf) is a current source based generator, that is, the reference voltage is set by the fixed 10uA flowing through the adjust pin and its external resistor. If so, I don't see (according to their schematic) why they say the input voltage is limited to 36V. Suppose for example I want to regulate a supply with 5V - 10V ripple at about 700V, and that I connect a 70MOhm resistor (approx.) to the adjust pin; how could the IC know that the input voltage is 700V since its reference is near the top voltage ?

Comment: Only the difference of voltages between the in and out pin imports here no ?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. This is one of those ICs that has no ground.

Comment: @MikeTeX It's basically a 3-pin device. All three pins must be within a range of at most \$36\:\text{V}\$. How would you ensure that with the recommended schematic?

Comment: It might have something to do with conditions on power-up. This is the only thing I think of. This would limit thing even if the 36Vmax is all technically relative to Vout. You might be able to push the startup envelope a bit, but I would think that the LT3080 could not withstand 700V even for a few microseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part actually supports 40V, it says 0 to 36V because that is the voltage range that the specifications of the part will work. The part has been tested for 0 to 36V.

The absolute maximum ratings are ratings for which the part will fail you can't go more than 40V *relative to Vout*

[image]

So you could do what you suggest if the voltage drop across a resistor was always more than 660V, thus keeping the voltage drop across the LT3080 under 40V.

Looks like it could work depending on the load:

[image]

Comment: See my comments (and DKNguyen's) elsewhere on this question.

Comment: I don't understand your last edit with the picture: you haven't put the output capacitor and your load is only 100 Ohm (at 700V you get 4900W Uh). Also the set resistor is only 1kOhm. How can it work with these settings?

Comment: There is nothing in the post about what current you need to regulate at or what your load is. The output cap adds *nothing to the simulation*, but would be required in real life, adding it doesn't make sense without the load. I was testing the idea of keeping the voltage within the range from a 700V source, which I didn't think was possible. Thats why I said "I think it *could* work", but I should edit my answer to I think it could work depending on the load

Comment: @VoltageSpike What about referencing the capacitor to the high side? Just as a starting thought.....

Comment: @jonk I guess it would depend on if you put the 3080 as a low side or high side current reference. If high side then that might be a good idea, if low side (like in the sch above) I'd keep it to ground.

Comment: Referencing the cap to the high side would give no regulation with respect to ground. On the contrary, this would add an horrible ripple (I think).

Comment: Well, I've finally found in the "Art of Electronics" a circuit that uses the LT3080 cleverly with some other parts to regulate from 1V to 500V (fig. 9.113 p. 698). Apparently, there is no problem with using the LT3080 as asked in my question, as the IC is submitted to the same voltages in their circuit.

Comment: Cool, I thought the LT3080 was a more recent part, looks like its been around for a while.